# Columns missing while adding new item in sharepoint List Definition

Tags: development

I have created a List Definition in SharePoint 2010 and added some fields in schema.xml

```
  <Fields>
  <Field ID="{24B3F6C1-B75B-4821-A466-C1E979B87B81}" Name="Manufacturer" DisplayName="Manufacturer" Type="Text" Required="TRUE"/>
  <Field ID="{24B3F6C1-B75B-4821-A466-C1E979B87B82}" Name="Model" DisplayName="Model" Type="Text" Required="TRUE"/>
  <Field ID="{24B3F6C1-B75B-4821-A466-C1E979B87B83}" Name="CPUMake" DisplayName="CPU Make" Type="Choice" Required="TRUE">
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>Intel</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>AMD</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Other</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
</Fields>
```

Added the view also

```
   <Views>
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Model"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="CPUMake"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Manufacturer"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
</Views>
```

I have activated the feature and created a list from moreoptions.But when i click to add new item it is only showing Title.

Comment: You have to add the fields as FieldRefs also

Comment: Please see the above code